# Putting div inside slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to add div with Menu inside div with my layer slider but I can't do it because it always goes above slider. Here's the look I want to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ5q0.jpg

When I wrote this code below, I noticed that my menu dissapear just before the first slide appears. How to fix it? Maybe I can disable my div from this "slider effects" ?

[Link to my website](http://www.spacemind.ggpro.pl/ar/)

```
<div id="full-slider-wrapper">

<div id="MENU" style="background-color:#000;float:right;width:80%;height:100px;"> random text </div>

    <div id="layerslider" style="width:100%;height:444px;">

        <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:1;timeshift:-1000;">
                <img src="sliderimages/fw-1.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background"/>
        </div>

        <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:1;timeshift:-1000;">
                <img src="sliderimages/fw-2.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background"/>
        </div>

        <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:1;timeshift:-1000;">
            <img src="sliderimages/fw-3.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background"/>
        </div>

        <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:1;timeshift:-1000;">
            <img src="sliderimages/fw-4.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the JS to analyze better, But seems like you could fix the position of the "main" header you want and give it a z index higher than that of the carousal of images underneath it.

Comment: I've been trying to fix it with z-index but always getting the same result. After loading of the image, menu disappear

Comment: can you post some more code ? And also a demo if you can

Comment: I've attached link to my webpage: http://www.spacemind.ggpro.pl/ar/
here's code I've put into index.html
http://pastebin.com/7abZqTGH

here's whole site code:
http://pastebin.com/8e8CayXQ

Comment: Here, try something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/euX5n1xkaWbPzszNxO6z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your menu's div should be outside of slider's div. Like this:

```
<div id="menu">
 <!--your menu code -->
</div>

<div id="slider">
  <!--your slider code -->
</div>
```

And maybe CSS can help:

```
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2; /* you can set 9999 to make it highest */
}
#slider{
  z-index:1; 
}
```

This W3C Schools links may help:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: When I Use position absolute, my menu goes left, don't know why. Unfortunately, menu still disappears...

Comment: By default all elements are floating left. You can add this style to menu : margin: 0px auto; And dont forget z-index!

Comment: Wow its nearly done.

when I put this

<div style="
  z-index:9999;
  background-color:#000;
  float:right;
  width:80%;
  position:absolute;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height:100px;"> random text </div>

My menu works correctly but it's being floated left.

Edit: Ok, I've got this. I added right:0px; and that solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake: absolute positioned elements can`t be centrered with margin: auto.  But there are some tricks. You can add margin: 20%, if your div is 80. Hope you`ll accept my answer.